# Parsing dates from csv with cassava

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to parse a csv file with data like this.  I can parse with the date as a string, but haven't been able to get them in a day format.  I finally got this to type check, but now I have a parse error and am hoping for some help.

```
2001/12/18, 281
2001/12/19, 280
2001/12/20, 276
2001/12/21, 278
```

Here's my code so far.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Time
import Generics.Deriving

datadir="/home/john/.stack/test/data/"  

data Sample = Sample { dateMeasure :: !Data.Time.Day 
                 , valueMeasure :: !Int 
                 } deriving (Generic, Show)   

instance FromRecord Sample 

instance FromField Data.Time.Day where
    parseField = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y/%m/%d" . show 

printRecord :: Sample -> IO ()
printRecord r  = putStrLn $  show (dateMeasure r) ++ " measurement is " ++    show (valueMeasure r) 

main :: IO ()
main = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile $ datadir ++ "sample.csv"
    case decode NoHeader csvData :: Either String (V.Vector Sample) of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right v -> V.forM_ v $ printRecord
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
~/.stack/test/ stack exec test
parse error (Failed reading: conversion error: parseTimeM: no parse of "\"2001/12/18\"") at 
2001/12/19, 280
2001/12/20, 276
2001/12/21, 278
2001/12/26, 278
2001/12/27, 278
2001/12/28, 2 (truncated)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `show`, which wraps the value in double quotes. `parseTimeM` is receiving the value `"\"2001/12/18\""`, and it doesn't know expect the quotes at the beginning and end of the string. Remove those quotes and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The question is pretty old, but I've just dealt with it myself, so let me post it here.

According to the manual, `parseField` is a function of type:

```hs
parseField :: Field -> Parser a
```

In our case we want type `a` to be `Day`, while `Field` is just a type alias

```hs
type Field = ByteString
```

The function that you use:

```
parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y/%m/%d"
```

Expects a `String`, not a `ByteString`. So in order to make everything correct, you need to provide an adapter function `ByteString -> String`.

Using `show` makes it all type check, but it has the flaw that it leaves the quotation marks in the resulting string.
A better choice would be to use `unpack` function that is meant to perform the conversion between the types.

So the entire code is:

```hs
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (unpack)

instance FromField Data.Time.Day where
    parseField = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y/%m/%d" . unpack
```